# Magento: Display multiple currencies in admin and frontend without currency rates

Tags: magento, product, currency, reward

I am trying to implement a new currency called "points" into my magento (CE 1.9.2.1) installation. I already installed this currency with my module and an installer script, marked it as allowed and I am possible to switch between "EUR" and "Points" in the frontend.

Here's the trick. Magento expects a currency rate for this new currency. But there's no currency rate, so that points can't be converted to EUR and EUR can't be converted to points. These currencies are independent.

The customers who are using this store should have the opportunity to buy this product with

- points (no reward points. you can not earn points by buying a product) OR
- EUR.

Therefore I'd like to know if there is a possibility to

- Display multiple currencies for products (Available for 5.00€ or 200 Points)
- Add a field in the admin product view (Price (€); Points). This field "points" has to be connected with my installed currency "points".

Do you have any ideas how to implement this? Any help would be appreciated.